# Can Commerce Kickstart be used to add Drupal Commerce to an existing site?

Tags: 7, commerce

I want to add the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module to my existing Drupal website. Is there any way I can use the [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) dstribution for an existing Drupal site?

Seems like you're supposed to use [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) when you're starting to build your Drupal site, but I already built mine.

According to the Commerce Kickstart website it says: "*Anyone who wants to skip weeks of configuration to build a commerce site on the Drupal Commerce framework*".

Is it really that hard to install the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) module without [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart)?

I'm not creating a big store, I just want to sell 1 or 2 items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not install an installation profile after Drupal has already been installed. What you can do is make a separate installation with Kickstart Commerce and compare configuration when you're stuck.

How hard Commerce is to install depends on you previous Drupal experience. If this is your first time around with Drupal, it will be pretty hard. But if you're already familiar with entities, views and rules, you'll be fine.

Comment: I'm very familiar with views and rules, not so much with entities. I'll read up on them. I am sure I'll figure it out. I'll follow your advice and make a separate kickstart install to compare stuff.

Comment: Ok, turns out I already know Entities.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Drupal e-Commerce - and have neither Drupal Commerce nor Ubercart - realize they are two different cart systems and that Ubercart is arguably better integrated to Drupal and Ubercart does a whole host of things especially in modules extensions Drupal Commerce does not.  You did not say if you installed Drupal 6 or 7 - but if you installed Drupal 6, go back and re-install or upgrade to Drupal 7 - as Ubercart for Drupal 6 is version 2 of Ubercart and for Drupal 7 it is version 3 and the two are like night and day.  You will find many of the top level Drupal Core code contributors are also Ubercart contributor developers also.  That should rest my case.

Comment: For what it's worth, this was true several years ago but is not true any longer. Additionally, Drupal Commerce was architected from the ground up on Drupal 7 around the fieldable entity system, so in no way is Ubercart "better integrated to Drupal." (I say this having written both.)

Comment: Possibly as you see it; however D6 had a lot of code for Ubercart that exist now in both D6 and 7  Drupal Commerce never did and as projects are now just getting going that do not have all the features Ubercart has.  A few that come to mind which are ready and integrate very well are EDI, Quickbooks, Reccuring subscriptions, Products and Fees, Stripe, Endicia.com does not exist as I know of, Sa tamps.com, and integration of automatic Postal Service label printing, UC_FedEx prints shipping labe4ls directly - Commerce FedEx is young and does not.  The list goes on but I am out of characters

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using the [Commerce Backoffice](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice) module. It provides the backoffice functionality present in [Commerce Kickstart (V2)](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart). It contains these sub-modules:

- Commerce Backoffice **Product** (commerce_backoffice_product).
- Commerce Backoffice **Order** (commerce_backoffice_order).
- Commerce Backoffice **Content** (commerce_backoffice_content).

This module (and a few dependencies) provides the rich store owner experience that has made Commerce Kickstart 2 so popular, and prevents that you have to install the entire Commerce Kickstart distribution. And there is a [great video introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkMZ_VcBan0) about it also.

If you use [Commerce Backoffice](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice), you most probably also want to use the [Shiny](https://www.drupal.org/project/shiny) administration theme, also used in [Commerce Kickstart (V2)](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart).

Comment: Thanks, I've never heard of Backoffice before, good video.